# Why is there no Overshoot in this second order system?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

A second-order system which has a damping factor of less than $1$ should have an overshoot right?

The formula for this is:

$$\exp{(-\pi*\zeta/\sqrt{1-\zeta^2})}$$

But I have noticed that if the time constant is very large, and the gain is very small, there is no overshoot whatsoever.

In MATLAB's Control System Toolbox, I simulated the transfer function $$g(s) = \frac{4.2}{s(1 + 6.91s)}$$ with a compensator of $K = 0.01$ in a closed-loop circuit with unity feedback. There should have been some overshoot and oscillation since the system is not critically damped, but there isn't!

Comment: please check that I denote your $g(s)$ transfer function well (the $1+6.91s$ factor is in the denominator?)

Comment: @gelichor thanks for the edit. Yes, that is correct

Comment: Are you  sure? try it, check the step response (step() function in matlab) for the closed loop transfer function TF=K*G/(1+K*G)

Comment: turns out that there is overshoot, it is just so small that it is not noticable at all. Guess its possible due to the really small gain that I am using